# Population of ComboBox with DisplayMember and ValueMember

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I am trying to populate Combox like this :

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id,name FROM table1", con);
        da.Fill(ds, "FillDropDown");

        comboProject.DisplayMember = "FillDropDown.name";
        comboProject.ValueMember = "FillDropDown.id";
        comboProject.DataSource = ds.Tables["FillDropDown"];
```

But all item are showing as "System.Data.DataRowView" in Combobox. why it is like that?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Warning. Using DisplayMember = "name", might malfunction when dotfuscating. Since it will no longer be called "name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try  comboProject.DataSource = ds.Tables["FillDropDown"].DefaultView;
```

Comment: @Pranav    try this  comboProject.DataSource = ds.Tables["FillDropDown"].DefaultView;comboProject.DisplayMember = "name";
        comboProject.ValueMember = "id";

Comment: actually i tried ..on just removing table name from display and value member it is working fine..but why it is like that..anyway thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id,name FROM table1", con);
da.Fill(ds, "FillDropDown");

comboProject.DisplayMember = "name";
comboProject.ValueMember = "id";
comboProject.DataSource = ds.Tables["FillDropDown"];
comboProject.DataBind();
```