# C# combobox displays wrong values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

[image]

I want to insert data into my ComboBox from the database. This is my code:

```
OracleDataTable dt = new OracleDataTable();
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "....string....";

string query = "SELECT emp_username FROM dc_emp";
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(query,conn);

da.Fill(dt);
rp.cbDelivery.DataSource = dt;
rp.cbDelivery.DisplayMember = "emp_username";
```

This works but its not 100%. I'm getting the right amount of fields in the combobox but the name value has been replace with CoreLab.Common.

So its definitely making the connection to the DB table and bringing back the right amount of fields but not in the right value...

Hope this makes sense.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe you'll get an idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104158/population-of-combobox-with-displaymember-and-valuemember), which is a similar question.

Comment: Maybe you just need a `DataTable` instead of `OracleDataTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback. I tried all your suggestions and at the end I found an example and modified it to work for me. This is the working code below:

```
        OracleDataReader dr;
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "....string....";
        string query = "SELECT distinct dd.delivery_bay_code FROM dc_delivery dd, dc_grv dg WHERE delivery_complete_datetime is null AND dd.dc_delivery_id_no = dg.dc_delivery_id_no";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            if (dr[0].ToString().Length > 2)
                cbDelivery.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this-

```
        rp.cbDelivery.DataSource = dt
        rp.cbDelivery.DisplayMember = "emp_username";
        rp.cbDelivery.ValueMember = "emp_username";
```

Also try with `Datatable dt= new DataTable();` instead of  `OracleDataTable dt = new OracleDataTable();`

Answer (score 0):

Assign ValueMember too:

rp.cbDelivery.ValueMember = "emp_username";

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should focus on the following line:

```
rp.cbDelivery.DisplayMember = "emp_username";
```

The problem could be caused by the fact that the `DataTable` column names do not include the one that you were referring to. Here's an example which probably reproduces your problem:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Alex" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "John" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Mary" });

comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name_with_typo"; //here you should use Name
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first use `DisplayMember` like this :

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("....string....");
string query = "SELECT emp_username FROM dc_emp";
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(query,conn);
OracleDataTable dt = new OracleDataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
rp.cbDelivery.DisplayMember = "emp_username";
rp.cbDelivery.DataSource = dt;
```